# Impala Dateformat error

Tags: impala

I have input values of

```
161223000001
```

I need to convert into

```
2016-12-23 00:00:01
```

I tried

```
select cast(161223000001 as timestamp)
7078-12-14 22:40:01
```

I am getting incorrect answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `to_timestamp` function to convert string to timestamp in Impala

```
SELECT to_timestamp('161223000001', 'yyMMddHHmmss');
```

By using `CAST AS TIMESTAMP` in your original attempt, it recognizes the given string as a unix epoch time instead

Comment: @abc Glad to help!